# Reading MVS dataset from a desktop application

Tags: java, unix, mainframe, ftp-client

Is it possible to read a MVS dataset using a FTP client in java ? But the condition is I cannot download that file to my local server. So I need to read it remotely and process the data at the remote server itself.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

Comment: Ummm... please provide the distinction between reading the MVS dataset and downloading it? FTP is a tool for downloading and logically reading is downloading **plus** a step... or are you asking if it's possible to execute arbitrary commands through ftp on mvs? Oh, and [maybe](https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/US-13-Young-Mainframes-The-Past-Will-Come-Back-to-Haunt-You-WP.pdf).

Comment: Ok..@Elliot. For eg if I have a MVS dataset and if I try reading that dataset using a web app, I can directly read it and parse the data. But when it comes to batch, what can we do to read the data of the dataset without downloading it?

Comment: Why can't you execute your Java program on the mainframe?

Comment: That's the requirement. @cschneid. I want to execute it from a local server

Comment: I don't understand. If the JAVA that is reading the data is running on the local server then the data is being downloaded to the local server.  Is your restriction that you cannot write the file to any disks on your local server?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called ZFile https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.70.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/ZFile.html  its an IBM library that will allow you access datasets on a mainframe without downloading anydata. I know nothing about how to use it (which is why this is a comment rather than an answer). also note that this will not allow to process the data on the remote server. It will still be "processed" on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutely possible to stream an MVS data set using an FTP client. I've done so using the Apache commons FTPClient library and there are several products that have been doing so for years including SAS/MSG. However, there are caveats. If the data set is VB you will need the `RDW (Record Descriptor Word)` which is 2 byte header that contains the length of the record. Use the `quote site rdw` FTP command to tell the z/OS FTP server you want the RDW. Note that the header is actually 4 bytes which is refered to as `LLZZ`, the `LL` is a 16-bit integer that contains the record length and the `ZZ` is just binary zeroes.

Comment: "But the condition is I cannot download that file to my local server" FTPing the file to the local server using the apache commons FTPClient library is downloading the file, so this will not work

Comment: Who said anything about storing to a local file? You can use FTPClient to stream the data using an InputStream so no need to hit the file system at all.